# pandas dataframe to correct data types after a split of a non-delimited text field

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I have an excel file with non-structured data.  1 column of text with 4 pieces of data and I am importing this into a dataframe... some of the data may not match the intended for the column

```
03/04/21    08:08:26  ->  -   50.20
03/04/21    11:08:26  ->  +  283.75
03/04/21    10:48:34  ->  Scale Timeout
```

I am able to `.split(' ', expand=True)` this to get 12 columns.

```
             0 1  2  3          4 5    6 7   8 9       10     11
0     03/04/21           08:08:26     ->     -             50.20
1     03/04/21           08:28:26     ->     -             50.20
```

this behaves like a typical dataframe as I copy cols[0,4,8,11], rename them and copy to a new df:

```
          date      time sign   mass
0     03/04/21  08:08:26    -  50.20
1     03/04/21  08:28:26    -  50.20
2     03/04/21  08:48:26    -  50.15
```

now things go south... I cannot even `print(df['date'])`

I get error:
only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

I've checked dtype, and all cols are type object.  I've tried to .astype(str), and still get the same error

#confused

It must be the .split() that is creating a dtype that I am not addressing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original dataframe with unstructured data:

df:

```
                                   col
0  03/04/21    08:08:26  ->  -   50.20
1  03/04/21    11:08:26  ->  +  283.75
2  03/04/21    10:48:34  ->  -  50.15
```

Then try below operation on your df:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.col.str.split().str.join(' ').str.split(' ').values.tolist(), columns=['date','time','symbol','sign','mass'])
```

df2:

```
       date      time symbol sign    mass
0  03/04/21  08:08:26     ->    -   50.20
1  03/04/21  11:08:26     ->    +  283.75
2  03/04/21  10:48:34     ->    -   50.15
```

df2 has all the different pieces of data as separate columns. Now you can just select the columns from df2 that you need.

```
print(df2['date'])
0    03/04/21
1    03/04/21
2    03/04/21
Name: date, dtype: object
```

What I did is first remove all the extra white-spaces in your unstructured data, and replace them with a single space. Then I applied `split(' ')` on that data to divide into required pieces of data.

Comment: This works, thanks.  if i am following correctly,  this is a much cleaner way of parsing the non-structured data into columns, and  pulls the data into the df in the correct format that can be recognized by pandas

Comment: Correct. There can be other cleaner ways as well based on how much non-structured the data is, but this one works fine for your case.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy to new df, then it will be new list.

You have to use print(df[0]) for printing date.
df[1] for time, df[2] for sign and df[3] for mass

> only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

**df is a list object, you can check data type of df, you can use only integers in index in list**

Comment: thanks for the input.  i don't understand why I am not able to address the columns by name since I have assigned names to each column after the `.split()` operation assigned integers, but the answer from @Ank has solved the issue